# Why does these three examples give different results? They seem to be equivalent

Tags: haskell

During my solving of AdventOfCode 2018 day 1 question 2 I ran into some weird behavior. The following code works as intended, and prints out the correct solution.

```
day1_2 = do
    content <- day1
    let content = scanl (+) 0 content
    return $ dup content
  where
    dup xs = dup' xs []
      where
        dup' [] _ = Nothing
        dup' (x : xs) seen =
            if x `elem` seen then Just x else dup' xs (x : seen)
```

It works, but I wanted to clean it up a little. As soon as I removed the second binding of `content`, and inlined the function call, the code stopped working. Since the `dup` function doesn't change I've omitted it from the rest of the snippets.

```
day1_2 = do
    content <- day1
    return $ dup $ scanl (+) 0 content
```

My understanding of Haskell tells me those two functions should give identical results, but they don't. On the input I've been given the first function returns `Just 0` while the second returns `Nothing`. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Reducing the code even more still keeps the behavior from the second function.

```
day1_2 = dup . scanl (+) 0 <$> day1
```

Here `day1` just reads the input given for day 1, and makes it parsable to Haskell.

```
day1 =
    map (read . (\n -> if head n == '+' then tail n else n))
        .   words
        <$> readFile "input/day1.txt"
```

Further weirdness:

```
day1_2 = do
    content <- day1
    let content' = scanl (+) 0 content
    return $ dup content
```

The above gives me `Just 6`. (Not the desired result, but that is expected)

```
day1_2 = do
    content <- day1
    let smth = scanl (+) 0 content
    return $ dup smth
```

The above, however, gives me `Nothing` even though it's functionally equivalent to the first snippet, save for some naming differences. From these last tests it's obvious that the `content` binding in the original is shadowed. However, if no shadowing is involved then the wrong output is given.

[My specific input for day1.](https://pastebin.com/v8TqZkjE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code is broken.

```
do content <- day1
   let content = scanl (+) 0 content
   _etc
```

Does not mean "bind the result of `day1` to `content`, apply `scanl (+) 0` to that, and bind that to `content`". Actually, what you've written is the same as this:

```
do day1
   let content = scanl (+) 0 content
   _etc
```

Which has you executing `day1`, discarding its result, and then binding to `content` a recursively defined list. You're correct that `content` is being shadowed, but you didn't realize that the second `content` shadowed the first one in its own definition. If you type `let content = scanl (+) 0 content in content`, you'll actually see you have an infinite list of `0`s. It should be obvious why you then get `Just 0` as an "answer."

The "correct" solution is actually the final one.

```
day1_2 = do content <- day1
            let smth = scanl (+) 0 content
            return $ dup smth
-- don't need do notation; just functor-function-application
day1_2 = dup <$> scanl (+) 0 <$> day1
```

But you are missing one crucial piece of the [question](https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/1#part2):

> Note that your device might need to repeat its list of frequency changes many times before a duplicate frequency is found

You need just one call to a single standard library function to make this work. See if you can find it :). (Fair warning: once you find the function and use it, this solution takes a good few minutes to finish running, but it does work.)

```
day1_2 = dup <$> scanl (+) 0 <$> _libfunction <$> day1
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `let content = scanl (+) 0 content`, the second `content` is **not** the `content` declared in the previous line, but `content` declared in this line using `let`.

So the first code just ignores `content` gotten from `day1`, but the second code uses it. That's why these two behave differently.